# Update HTML Text Fields

Tags: html

How can I update the text fields with HTML? I have a page with some textfields, and I need to update these fields at a specific time. I used the *value* property to display the default values, but how can I change the values later?

Thank you

Comment: you can't update fields with html, html is not able to do any processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am forcing a `JavaScript` answer, since there is no way it can be done with only `HTML`.

Snippet:

```
<input type="text" id="textboxid" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtBox = document.getElementById("textboxid");
    txtBox.value = "new value";
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. Actually, I have to write the code in a JSP file, so how can I do this? I wrote the above code with <%, but that didn't work.

Comment: @user1178619, No, you should use it inside `<script>`, I have updated my answer. But noted that will will run right away when the script is loaded. So, put the above snippet beneath the textbox to get the desired output.

Comment: @user1178619, Looks like you are fairly new to the community. So, you should always [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) once they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript in order to achieve this.  I recommend jQuery, as it prevents most cross-browser "quirks" and "gotchas".  Specifically, you're looking for http://api.jquery.com/html/ or http://api.jquery.com/val/.

`JSFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/dEUH5/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the very least, HTML is used for Mark-Up, CSS is for styling, and JavaScript is for functionality. I suggest that if you want to add functionality and interactivity to your website, you look up how to use JavaScript. This will allow you to add the functionality you wish for your textbox, as you wished.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with HTML, you could with PHP.

I'm sure someone will type out the code, but go to: http://uk.php.net/.

This question is way to broad too.